# NuGet Push Error 500 (without Proxy), Error 503 (with Proxy)

Tags: azure-devops, nuget

I try to Push a `nupkg` to a Artifacts in a Azure DevOps Server.
The network is behind a proxy so my `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="FrameworkA" value="http://xfc-l-s6fc5086:8070/Samples/_packaging/FrameworkA/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="http://my-proxy:8000" />
    <add key="http_proxy.user" value="domain\user" />
    <add key="http_proxy.password" value="*** windows security key ***" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

**From my feed (Azure DevOps) page I get the following information:**

[image]

---

**so if I execute:**

`nuget.exe push -Source "FrameworkA" -ApiKey AzureDevOps .\FrameworkA.1.0.0.nupkg`

I get:

`The response status code does not indicate success: 503 (Service Unavailable).`

I remove the proxy information from my `nuget.config` and I get:

```
The response status code is unsuccessful: 500 (Internal Server Error - Error retrieving data from the upstream packet source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json): Error sending the request. (DevOps activity ID: 69FB4414-ED0B-4367-B121-B0DC9B366367)).
```

And I also get this meaasge when I remove the entry:

`<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />`

Whats going wrong here? Has anybody experience with Azure DevOps Server behind a proxy? (everything else with azure devops server works fine, REST API, Custom Extension, Build- and release tasks and so on)

*Version: 17.143.28912.1 (AzureDevOps2019.0.1)*

Comment: Have you set any proxy in you environment? If yes, try to remove it, then re-push the package to check if you still have this issue.

Comment: @Joy thanks for that input. I try different things inside windows proxy settings: **1.** switch `use proxy server` to false **2.** add the server ip to proxy by pass **3.** switch `do not use proxy server for internal adresses` to true/false. In each case I try it multiple times with and without proxy settings inside the `nuget.config`. Nothing change, all error messages was the same, some cases `500`, some cases `503`. I also try to access the feed.json manually with browser, and I realize that I only have access with the num based ip version of the server (`http://138.202.16.216:8070/Sa...`)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same and solved it because of a typo. If I add the DevOps as Proxy it works.

```
<add key="http_proxy" value="http://devops.yourdomain:8080" />
```

That worked im my case. IDK why!

Comment: unfortunately for me it don't helps, but thanks for the input.